# Como ingresar varias veces un producto con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación de productos como ejercicio con Bootstrap y Jquery , ya tengo bastante avanzada la aplicación, pero estoy teniendo un problema para cargar los productos, cuando cargo un producto este genera un cuadro con los datos ingresados y un botón para poder eliminarlo,el problema es que cuando borro uno de los productos con el botón se borra todo el cuadro y no me deja seguir cargando productos.
Saludos.

```js
function suma(){
  var especie;
  var cantidad;
  var precio;
  var total;
  especie = document.getElementById('especie').value;
  cantidad = document.getElementById('cant').value;
  precio = document.getElementById('compra').value;
  total = cantidad*precio;
  document.getElementById('subtotal').value = total;

  if(total > 0){
  
    

    $(".cuadro2").append(`
      
      <p class='col-3'>${especie}</p>
      <p class='col-2'>${cantidad}</p>
      <p class='col-2'>${precio}</p>
      <p class='col-3'>${total}</p>
      <p class="col-2"><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='-' onclick='borrar()' ></p>
      
    `)

  }
  
  // Muestro u oculto el encabezado de la tabla dependiende de si esta vacia o no

  if ($('.cuadro2').children().length) {
    
    $(".parrafo").removeClass("invisible")
    
    $(".parrafo").show()
    
    $(".cuadro").removeClass("invisible")
    
    $(".cuadro").show()
    
    reset();
    
    

  } else {

    $(".parrafo").hide()

    $(".cuadro").hide()

  }

};

function borrar(){
  $("p").remove("");
  $(".cuadro2").remove("")
};

function reset(){
     document.getElementById('especie').value = "";
     document.getElementById('cant').value = "";
     document.getElementById('compra').value = "";
     document.getElementById('subtotal').value = "";
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


.container{
  height: 600px;
  width: auto;

}

.ct1{
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.invisible{
 display: none;
}

.cuadro{
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.cuadro2{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Movizen Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container bg-primary">

      <div class="row text-white ct1">
        <div class="col">Especie</div>
        <div class="col">Cantidad</div>
        <div class="col">Precio($)</div>
        <div class="col">Total($)</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row ct2">
        <input class="col" type="text" id="especie" placeholder="Especie">
        <input class="col"type="text" id="cant" placeholder="Cantidad">
        <input class="col" type="text" id="compra" placeholder="Precio compra">
        <input class="col" type="text" id="subtotal" placeholder="Total" disabled>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" placeholder="Total" onclick="suma()" id="sum" value="+" />
      </div>

      <p class="parrafo invisible">Su cartera contiene los siguientes elementos:</p>

      <div class="row cuadro invisible">
        <p class='col-3'>Especie</p>
        <p class='col-2'>Cantidad</p>
        <p class='col-2'>Precio($)</p>
        <p class='col-3'>Total($)</p>
        <p class='col-2'>Acción</p>
      </div>

      <div class="cuadro2 row"></div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola en la parte de tu html del div **cuadro2** quitale la clase row. para que quede asi

```
<div class="cuadro2"></div>
```

Y tu el js debe quedar asi.

```
function suma(){
  var especie;
  var cantidad;
  var precio;
  var total;
  especie = document.getElementById('especie').value;
  cantidad = document.getElementById('cant').value;
  precio = document.getElementById('compra').value;
  total = cantidad*precio;
  document.getElementById('subtotal').value = total;

  if(total > 0){
    $(".cuadro2").append(`<div class="row">
      <p class='col-3'>${especie}</p>
      <p class='col-2'>${cantidad}</p>
      <p class='col-2'>${precio}</p>
      <p class='col-3'>${total}</p>
      <p class="col-2"><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='-' 
      onclick='borrar(event)' ></p></div>
    `)
  }

  // Muestro u oculto el encabezado de la tabla dependiende de si esta vacia o no
  if ($('.cuadro2').children().length) {
    $(".parrafo").removeClass("invisible");
    $(".parrafo").show();
    $(".cuadro").removeClass("invisible");
    $(".cuadro").show();
    reset();
  } else {
    $(".parrafo").hide();
    $(".cuadro").hide();
  }

};

function borrar(e){
  $(e.target).parent().parent().remove();
  if($('.cuadro2').find('.row').length===0){
    $('.parrafo').hide();
    $('.cuadro').hide();
  }
}

function reset(){
     document.getElementById('especie').value = "";
     document.getElementById('cant').value = "";
     document.getElementById('compra').value = "";
     document.getElementById('subtotal').value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function suma() {
  var especie;
  var cantidad;
  var precio;
  var total;
  especie = document.getElementById("especie").value;
  cantidad = document.getElementById("cant").value;
  precio = document.getElementById("compra").value;
  total = cantidad * precio;
  document.getElementById("subtotal").value = total;

  if (total > 0) {
    $(".cuadro2").append(`
      <div class='col-12 boxRowElements'>
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-3'> <p>${especie}</p></div>
        <div class='col-2'><p>${cantidad}</p></div>
        <div class='col-2'><p>${precio}</p></div>
        <div class='col-3'><p>${total}</p></div>
        <div class='col-2'><p><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' value='-' onclick='borrar(event)' ></p></div>
        </div>
        </div>
      `);
  }

  // Muestro u oculto el encabezado de la tabla dependiende de si esta vacia o no

  if ($(".cuadro2").children().length) {
    $(".parrafo").removeClass("invisible");

    $(".parrafo").show();

    $(".cuadro").removeClass("invisible");

    $(".cuadro").show();

    reset();
  } else {
    $(".parrafo").hide();

    $(".cuadro").hide();
  }
}

function borrar(event) {
  debugger;
  $(event.target)
    .closest(".boxRowElements")
    .remove();
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("especie").value = "";
  document.getElementById("cant").value = "";
  document.getElementById("compra").value = "";
  document.getElementById("subtotal").value = "";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  height: 600px;
  width: auto;
}

.ct1 {
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.cuadro {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.cuadro2 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Movizen Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container bg-primary">

    <div class="row text-white ct1">
      <div class="col">Especie</div>
      <div class="col">Cantidad</div>
      <div class="col">Precio($)</div>
      <div class="col">Total($)</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ct2">
      <input class="col" type="text" id="especie" placeholder="Especie">
      <input class="col" type="text" id="cant" placeholder="Cantidad">
      <input class="col" type="text" id="compra" placeholder="Precio compra">
      <input class="col" type="text" id="subtotal" placeholder="Total" disabled>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" placeholder="Total" onclick="suma()" id="sum" value="+" />
    </div>

    <p class="parrafo invisible">Su cartera contiene los siguientes elementos:</p>

    <div class="row cuadro invisible">
      <div class='col-3'>Especie</div>
      <div class='col-2'>Cantidad</div>
      <div class='col-2'>Precio($)</div>
      <div class='col-3'>Total($)</div>
      <div class='col-2'>Acción</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cuadro2 row"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Estabas insertando los elementos de un solo montón. Tenias que tener un identificador por "fila" y después eliminar dicho elemento.